# Where to find drawable-resources belonging to the android AnalogClock?

Tags: android, clock

I want to implement a customized AnalogClock and therefore I copied the default implementaion from android.widget.AnalogClock as a base. The implementation itself refers to some drawables (dial, minute_hand, hour_hand) which are all prefixed by "com.android.internal.R.*". Where can I find those resources, if I want to reuse them, I cannot reference them from within my own program?

Comment: In your SDK path. In my case it is: `C:\Program Files\Adt-Bundle\sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res` (18 indicates an API Level - You might choose another). Here you will find the drawable folders.

Comment: thanks, helped a lot ! The clock-drawables are located in the drawables-hdpi folder.

Comment: But also in the other `drawables-*dpi` folders. So, it depends on which resolution(s) you want to support.